# copy records from one table to another query give error sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using the below query to copy records from one table to another, but i get error

```
insert into table1 (datestamp)
select datestamp
from table2
where table1.datestamp is null
```

I want to copy records of datestamp from table 2 to table 1 where datestamp in table 1 is null.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
insert into table1 (datestamp)
select datestamp
from table2
where table2.datestamp is null
```

You are referencing table1 datestamp in the `where` clause and this is not allowed.

Perhaps you really want an `update`.  If so, you need a way to link the two tables:

```
update t1
    set datestamp = t2.datestamp
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.datestamp is null
```

Comment: Hehe... beat me to the answer.  :-)

Comment: i used the above query. it gives me error saying "invalid object name t1"
'
    UPDATE       t1
    SET                t1.DateStamp = t2.DateStamp
    FROM            Table4 AS t1 INNER JOIN
    date AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID CROSS JOIN
    t1
    WHERE        (t1.DateStamp IS NULL)'

Comment: @ssaaddii You're receiving the error because you can't specify a table alias in a join; you would need to state `CROSS JOIN Table4` in this case. But you shouldn't need the cross join, anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the tables are tied together by some unique id?  We'll call that tableID.

```
UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t2
SET t1.datestamp = t2.datestamp
WHERE t1.datestamp IS NULL
AND t1.tableID = t2.tableID
```